# How can I ignore extra fields when inserting JSON into a Cassandra table?

Tags: json, cassandra

With Cassandra, I can [load JSON into a table](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#insert):

```
INSERT INTO foo.bar JSON '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}';
```

However, if the column `bar` doesn't exist, Cassandra complains:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="JSON values map contains unrecognized column: bar"
```

Can I make Cassandra insert identified columns and skip the unknown ones?

Comment: please , be more specific about your environment is that pure JAVA or thru SPARK , or SCALA ?

Comment: @PatrickBoulay since I'm not doing any programming, are you asking what Cassandra is written in?

Comment: @muru did you solved it?